Why present progressive in this context
a person is speaking or writing about his strategy to buy records

"buy in stacks and  buy cheap. I'll spend  60 bucks  on a stacks  of twenty 3  dollar  records. Ten records are crap, five are good  but not great , three are pretty damn fine  and two blow my mind. If I dump the ten crappos  for nothing, I'm paying six bucks a pop, a very reasonable  price

First he used future ok I understand then switched to present I can also understand it is a fact (a general truth. It is mathematical)  but why present progressive, is it used as future? why not going to pay?

Note that, in English, it is not normal to put a space before punctuation.  For example,    "...buy cheap .I 'll..." should be "...buy cheap. I'll..."

Should read " three-dollar records" (singular "dollar").

Don't begin your passage with part of a sentence lopped off as you have done.

@TimR Are you sure that something is lopped off? "Buy in stacks and buy cheap." Is a complete sentence.

@JavaLatte:  The lower case "b" and the fact that there's a missing close-quote made me think something had been mangled or not included.

This looks like very informal spoken English: it's perfectly normal to have inconsistencies of all sorts in spoken English, and even more so for informal English.
In this particular case, he or she is describing something that they do regularly - a habitual action. Will (and would) can be used in this way, and so can present continuous.

You can use the simple present and the present continuous to talk about events in the future that are already decided, planned, or scheduled. This is fairly common in English.  These are often used with hypothetical "if" constructions, and/or expressions of time.  The context makes it clear we are talking about something in the future.
Some similar examples

If I buy a 2kg bag of potatoes for £1.59, and there are ten potatoes
in the bag, then I'm paying approximately 16p per potato.
If Mary arrives before 10am, she is having breakfast with us at Toni's Café. If she can't make it in time, then I'm cooking lunch at home instead.
The train leaves/is leaving at 8pm tonight.


so in my example it is not clear what  the reference is  because the example given is in the future but i am paying could be present (I am doing it) or future (will do it soon ) it is a bit ambiguous but if it was future it  would be indicated (adverb of time or some words relating to the time  ). So it should be present but how can we use present when  the beginning example is in the future

@YvesLefol - it's not ambiguous to English speakers. You could use "going to pay" in the example sentence, but it's not obligatory.  There are many ways to talk about the future. This is just another way to do it.

yes I  know  there are many ways to talk about the future but I am paying is it present or future ?

And if it is present why continuous  unless he is doing it , generally paying is not an action extended over time or that does not last a long time .

We can use "I am paying" for a future planned event. Another example.  "We are going to a restaurant tomorrow. You can come along if you want. I'm paying for the meal!".  This means I am planning to pay for the meal. It hasn't happened yet, but it is what I am planning to do.

@YvesLefol I've found this article which might help you. It's about using the present continuous to talk about the future.

@YvesLefol - also there's a nice video on youtube which explains it in even more depth.

so i am paying is future in my example

but  in this video there is a signal word for each example as in yours  but  not in my example that is why I  don't understand  the choice of present progressive

Yes. In the example, the future is already mentioned. He says "I'll spend 60 bucks".  This is the context. It's already about the future. And so when he says "I'm paying" we know that it is what he is planning or deciding to do in the future. You need to look at the section in the video that talks about the context where there is no "signal" word.  We only know this from the context.  If I ask you "Are you coming tomorrow?", you can reply "Sorry, I can't, I'm playing football".   This means you have a plan to play football tomorrow (in the future).

ok so  will is the signal word here
